# Link indexPath to a specsfic cell forever

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

When in scrolling my collection view(tableView) as long i scrolling my indexPath changes for cells, is there any way to link indexPath with cell (like a creating property in Cell subclass or something like that) cam someone show an example ?

Comment: Why? Cells are reused. You need to write your code properly to deal with that. Please explain, in your question, why you think you need the indexPath to stay constant for a given cell instance.

Comment: @rmaddy I want to transform cells rotation and make a canvas from visible cells and after some scrolling my canvas brakes cause of different indexPath